# AWS Glue Dynamo Extract

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I exported DYnamoDB table to S3, and used [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-sources-glue.html) to import into AThena. Each column is an entire dynam entry.

I get:

```
Item
{key={s=value1}, key2={n=value2}}
{key={s=value3}, key2={n=value4}}
{key={s=value5}, key2={n=value6}}
```

When I expected

```
key     key2
value1  value2
value3  value4
value5  value6
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with the json path in a custom classifier, but don't know where to go next.

Comment: DynamoDB data always contain the data type (e.g., String, Number) as a key. Glue ETL provides a built-in method `unnest_ddb_json`, but let us know if you prefer to use other method to process the data. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-unnest_ddb_json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on the crawler you can create your own external table which will allow you to define the schema manually:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ddb_exported_table (
  Item struct <id:struct<S:string>,
               name:struct<S:string>,
               coins:struct<N:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://my-dynamodb-export-bucket/AWSDynamoDB/{EXPORT_ID}/data/'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'has_encrypted_data'='true');
```

You can also use a CTAS query to create a table based on your results:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-insert-into-etl.html

Or perhaps do something as simple as this:

```
SELECT
    Item.id.S as id,
    Item.name.S as name,
    Item.coins.N as coins
FROM ddb_exported_table
ORDER BY cast(coins as integer) DESC
```

Comment: I used the second method, I was hoping there was a way to do as one step.